# Java JDO Problem (Google App Engine), What after (PersistenceManager)pm.close

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm a newbie in JDO. I use eclipse.

After I use (PersistenceManager) pm.close for test, now I delete this pm.close. However I still could not find a way to open or create a new one, even after I restarted the computer.

Every time, PersistenceManager show this error, Object Manager has been closed

And I could not find a way to direct edit JDO records.

Could you help me? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for that?

http://db.apache.org/jdo/api20/apidocs//javax/jdo/PersistenceManagerFactory.html#getPersistenceManager()

and

http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjdo.html

querying:

http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html

(i don't want to copy all this here)

(you dont need to restart your computer)

Comment: I read all of them, could not find a solution. I just want to restore this app to the previous state(without using PersistenceManager.close)